# Notice: Undefined index: err

Tags: php, html

Есть форма

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="event" value="signup"/>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="input-email"><?=_('Логин')?></label>
            <input name="uname" value="" placeholder="<?=_('Логин')?>" id="input-email" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="input-password"><?=_('Пароль')?></label>
            <input name="pwd" value="" placeholder="<?=_('Пароль')?>" id="input-password" class="form-control" type="password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
    <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="1"/> <?=_('Запомнить')?>
          </div>
```

Обработчик формы работает норм, но есть проблема в том, что не срабатывает валидация и выдает ошибку Notice: Undefined index: err

```
<?if($_GET['err']=='1'):?><div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
    <?=_('Вы ввели неправильный логин или пароль')?>
</div><?endif?>
```

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['err']))`

Comment: Я пробовал так сделать. Ошибка пропадает, но валидация все равно не работает.

Comment: Что значит не работает?

Comment: ввожу рандомный символы в форму, нажимаю войти и у меня просто сбрасывается все.

Comment: А что должно происходить? У вас, во-первых, форма не отправляет нигде `err`, во-вторых, у вас форма `post` запрос отправляет.

Comment: Если логин и пароль пользователя в бд есть, то она пропускает, а при ошибке сбрасывается. А как мне сделать, чтоб она err отправила ?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно проверить сначала, есть ли такой элемент в `$_GET`:

```
$err = isset($_GET['err']) ? $_GET['err'] : '0;
```

[Документация](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php#example-78):

> Relying on the default value of an uninitialized variable is
>   problematic in the case of including one file into another which uses
>   the same variable name. It is also a major security risk with
>   register_globals turned on. E_NOTICE level error is issued in case of
>   working with uninitialized variables, however not in the case of
>   appending elements to the uninitialized array. isset() language
>   construct can be used to detect if a variable has been already
>   initialized.